# Search for the existance of many objects in a database

Tags: mysql, facebook

Say I have a database with 5 million users, with the columns

`id (unsigned int, auto-increment), facebook_id (unsigned int), and name (varchar)`

In a program, I have a list of a variable amount of users from a person's facebook friend list (generally ranging from 500-1200 different facebook ids).

What's the most efficient way to send a query to my database that returns the facebook_id's of all of the users where that same facebook_id exists in the database?

Pseudo-code:

`$friends = array(12345, 22345, 32345, 42345, 52345, ... ~1000 more);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ...");
$friendsAlreadyUsingApp = parseQuery($q);`

Comment: Load the output of the program into a (temporary) table and then use a simple JOIN

Comment: @Matt any news on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a topic of almost an endless number of articles, blogs, Q&As etc; and the essence of this problem is that it looks really simple - but isn't.

The heart of the problem is that the parameters **looks like** it should work using `WHERE field IN()` BUT it does not do that because **the parameter is a single string** that just happens to have lots of commas in it.

So, when that parameter is passed to SQL it is necessary to process that single string into multiple parts so that the field can be compared to each part. This is where it gets a little complex as not all database types have all the same features to handle this. MySQL for example does not have a table variable that MS SQL Server provides.

So. A simple method, for MySQL is this:

```
SET @param := '105,110,125,135,145,155,165,175,185,195,205';

SELECT
*
FROM Users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(facebook_id, @param) > 0
;
```

> [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) Return the index position of the first argument
>   within the second argument

Just how well this scales in your database I cannot tell, it might not be acceptable for parameters containing 1000+ id's.

So if text processing like `FIND_IN_SET` is too slow, then each id needs to be broken out from the parameter and inserted into a table. That way the resulting table can be used through an `INNER JOIN` to filter the users; but this requires a table and inserts which take time, and there may be concurrency issues if more than one user is attempting to use that table at the same time.

---

Using the following sets-up a table of 10,000 integers (1 to 10,000)

```
/* Create a table called Numbers */
CREATE TABLE `Numbers`
(
    `Number` int PRIMARY KEY
);

/* use cross joins to create 10,000 integers from 1 & store into table */
INSERT INTO Numbers (Number)
select 1 + (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a))  as N
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
;
```

This "utility table" can then be used to divide a comma separated parameter into a derived table of the individual integers, and this then used in an `INNER JOIN` to your users table will provide the wanted result.

```
SET @param := '105,110,125,135,145,155,165,175,185,195,205';
SET @delimit := ',';

SELECT
      users.id
    , users.facebook_id
    , users.name
FROM users
      INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        CAST(SUBSTRING(iq.param, n.number + 1, LOCATE(@delimit, iq.param, n.number + 1) - n.number - 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS itemID
                  FROM (
                              SELECT
                                    concat(@delimit, @param, @delimit) AS param
                        ) AS iq
                        INNER JOIN Numbers n
                                    ON n.Number < LENGTH(iq.param)
                  WHERE SUBSTRING(iq.param, n.number, 1) = @delimit
            ) AS derived
                  ON users.facebook_id = derived.itemID
;
```

This query can be used as the basis for a stored procedure which might be easier for you to call from PHP.

[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34873/1)