# how to use IN() function inside of stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have using mysql with stored procedure. Inside of strored procedure i have write the select query with IN() function. I have pass the 5 value inside of the function but it display the first value data's only.my code is

> DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro1`(IN
>   `reg_id` VARCHAR(50))
>
> BEGIN
>
> SELECT COUNT(master_country_id) AS num FROM master_country WHERE master_region_id IN(reg_id) ORDER BY master_country_id DESC;
>
> END$$
>
> DELIMITER ;

the countries are,

1 - India

2 - Australia

3 - Canada

4 - Spain

5 - Srilanka

I have call the procedure is

> CALL pro1(1,4,2);

The actual Result is,

India,Spain,Australia

But It display the result is,

India

Comment: how many parameters are there? ONE, how many in your result? ONE. Just because that varchar(50) string LOOKS like 3 values, it is just ONE VALUE that contains commas.

Comment: See if this answer makes sense to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839148/search-for-the-existance-of-many-objects-in-a-database/25840260#25840260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE pro1(reg_id VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(master_country_id) AS num FROM master_country WHERE master_region_id REGEXP (reg_id) ORDER BY master_country_id DESC;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

you can call your proc as `CALL pro1('1|4|2');`

Comment: It's Working but the region id is more than 10 the all region are displayed. For example  10 - aaa, 12 - bbb, 13 - ccc, 14 - ddd means the all region are displayed when i call the procedure CALL pro1('1|4|2'); How can i get the particular regions only..

Comment: CALL pro1('^1$|^4$|^2$');

if you want the same variable use ^ before and $ in the end

Answer (score 0):

You cannot quite use `in` the way that you want.  The way your code is phrased, the stored procedure only finds a match when a master region matches a full string.  So, if you pass in `1,2,3`, then the match is on exactly that `1,2,3` -- not on each element.

You can get what you want using `find_in_set()`:

```
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(master_country_id) AS num
FROM master_country
WHERE find_in_set(reg_id, master_region_id) > 0
ORDER BY master_country_id DESC;

END$$
```

This works, but it cannot make use of an index.

You could use dynamic SQL (`prepare`/`exec`) as well, but that incurs overhead on compiling the query.